# "Save up to 50% off"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> Save up to 50% off!

Is this correct? To me, it makes it sound like a double-negative, of sorts; you are saving something that has been reduced, therefore increasing it, if that makes any sense. Anyhow, would it be more correct to say this?

> Save up to 50%!

Comment: The meaning is clear enough to me. If there were ever any dispute about it, I suppose it would be for a court to decide.

Comment: This phrasing bothers me as well.  It makes it sound as though English has the compound verb "*save off," which is just silly. It could be improved with a simple comma: Save, up to 50% off!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not mathematically or grammatically correct - but its meaning is clear enough.

"Save up to 50%!"  or "Savings of up to 50%!" would be correct.

Unless they are trying some subtle legal trick of actually reducing the discount from  50% to 25% and claiming that they are telling the truth and that halving the saving is "saving 50% off".

Comment: It's best to ignore such claims anyway, and look at the price tag.

Comment: Save upto 50%, the discount is 1% - well that's less than 50% and we did say "upto" !

Comment: I think in most US jurisdictions they are required to have something that is 50% off or else they are doing false advertising.

Comment: On what basis do you say it isn't grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

> Save up to %50 off

is just pleonastic, not a double negative.

Yes, it would be simpler to say

> Save up to %50.

or

> Get up to %50 off.

In the first statement, you're not really able to parse it as an object of '%50 off' in one direction which you then 'save' in the other direction. They just reinforce each other, but the extra 'off' is not really needed.

Comment: It doesn't seem ungrammatical to me. I read *up to* as an adjective modifying the noun *50% off* which I read as *the amount of the reduction*. That amount is indeed what you will save, and it will be 0% - 50% of the benchmark price. I can see why people think the *off* is superfluous, but I think it's quite clever, actually. Gets your attention, at least!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's redundant. You could say, "Save up to 50%", or "Up to 50% off" and it would mean the same thing.

As someone noted, be careful of any add that says "up to" 50% off. The only thing that statement actually promises is that they won't give you a discount of more than 50%. I take it for granted when I see such an ad that there is one item in the store that is 50% off, and everything else has considerably smaller discounts.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad english. Overkill.  It's funny over-stating something can dilute the intended message.

Comment: Where I was schooled, “bad english” is autological due to its manifest submajusculation.